# How to compare two elapsed times?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code that will show me always the slowest execution time of some code:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin, end
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds> lastElapsed;

begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

... some processing to be measured ...

end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count();

if (elapsed > lastElapsed)
{
    std::cout << "The slowest execution interval is now at  " << elapsed << "us" << std::endl;
    lastElapsed = elapsed;
}
```

I can't compile:

```
/home/user/dev/MyThread.cpp:104:59: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘lastElapsed’
     std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds> lastElapsed;
                                                           ^
/home/user/dev/MyThread.cpp:104:70: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
     std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds> lastElapsed;
                                                                      ^
/home/user/dev/MyThread.cpp:114:19: error: ‘lastElapsed’ was not declared in this scope
     if (elapsed > lastElapsed)
```

How can I fix this interval comparer and set the `lastElapsed` variable type accordingly?

Comment: Why not keep `elapsed` and `lastElapsed` *as* [durations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration)?

Comment: As for (a part of) your problem, `std::ducation_cast<...>` is not a valid *type*.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the previous line. I recommend using an editor / IDE that will catch these issues for you.

Comment: @Kevin, fixed. Tks.

Comment: And ***don't edit your question to incorporate fixes***, unless they are there in your original code and you just forgot about them. It makes answers and comments worthless.

Comment: [`duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) is a function. You're trying to use it as a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `std::chrono::duration_cast` is not a type, its function that returns a duration, so your declaration of `lastElapsed` is invalid. You can fix it like this:

```
auto lastElapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin);
```

which essentially initializes  `lastElapsed` with a value of 0.

Then when you compute `elapsed` use the same type:

```
auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin);
```

don't bother with the `count()` member function, until you need to output the value:

```
    std::cout << "The slowest execution interval is now at  " << elapsed.count() << " us" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin, end;
    std::chrono::microseconds lastElapsed;

    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    //... some processing to be measured ...

    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin);

    if (elapsed > lastElapsed)
    {
        std::cout << "The slowest execution interval is now at  " << elapsed.count() << "us" << std::endl;          
    }

    lastElapsed = elapsed;
```